# .htaccess and differentiating between query strings by case

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I wonder if someone can advise please?

After migrating an old php site to Wordpress, I converted some 450+ old pages to static html and used the following very satisfactorily;

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ID=([0-9]+) [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) {domain}/{filename}%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

However, a handy search plug-in also uses "id"  [lower case] in its URLs and these are being routed to the static page with the same numerical id.

Is there a way of detecting uppercase 'ID' only for the redirect and ignore lower case?  I appreciate it is poor coding, but I am unable to change either Query String names.

Sincere thanks for any guidance!

Comment: What do you think the `NC` flag you explicitly used there, stands for …?

Comment: Well removing it was the first thing I tried and it had no effect.